# Odoo webshop Add input field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I am using odoo ecommerce and I am setting up my own webshop. This shop doesn't need to have any shipping methods, however clients need to come and pick up the packages. I wanted an option for clients to select their own delivery date(time). I have been able to add a field where they can select this date(time), but this however doesn't get linked up to the model, where I also created the same field.

This is what I'm editing into the view

```
     <input id="x_pickup_date" type="date" name="Pickup date" class="form-control o_website_form_input o_website_form_date"/>
```

This shows the field properly, but how do I make this field be saved in sale.order?

Thanks for any help

J

Comment: you need to learn python as well. not only xml

Comment: Would you be able to provide more info about that? I've created the field already, and I can make the field show up/be saved using the form, but not using the website.

Comment: you need to provide us with more code to help